# Cannot git push to repo

Tags: git, github

I am a rookie. I try to finish my project work.

Here is my problem. When I try to push the document to the "datasciencecoursera" repo created on Github, I was trapped into some difficulties. The followings are what I have down:

```
LYtekiMacBook-Pro:datasciencecoursera LY$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   HelloWorld.md

LYtekiMacBook-Pro:datasciencecoursera LY$ git remote -v
origin  https://yuanliugit@github.com/yuanliugit/datasciencecoursera.git (fetch)
origin  https://yuanliugit@github.com/yuanliugit/datasciencecoursera.git (push)
LYtekiMacBook-Pro:datasciencecoursera LY$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

However, when I refreshed the website of the repo page, I found that there was nothing changed. The new document "HelloWorld.md" is not uploaded to the repo.

I do not know where is wrong. BTW, I use OS X system.

I really appreciate anyone who could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `git commit` your change before you push; `git` stores only *committed* states.

EDIT: Since this seems to be a beginner's question, I think it would be wise to add a link to a fundamental git intro: [Try Git by CodeSchool](https://try.github.io)

Answer (score 1):

First you must `git add .` your file to the staging area.  Then you must `git commit -m "enter your message here"`.  Then `git push origin master` That will do the trick.

Comment: Note: That is *one* of several ways to stage and commit changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have finished my work. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thats great. I'm glad to help, could you mark this answer as correct then.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations with taking the data science course! You will soon get your head around git. There are some great cheatsheets out there that will help whilst you are getting to grips with it. This course is also great. https://try.github.io
As mentioned above just remember it in three separate parts. Add, Commit and push.